# Is it possible to UILocalizedIndexedCollation with UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uilocalizedcollation

Is it possible to UILocalizedIndexedCollation with a UICollectionView? I'm using UICollectionView to show data but I want to use UILocalizedIndexedCollation like iOS contacts with it. I didn't find a way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please take a look at [BDKCollectionIndexView](https://github.com/kreeger/BDKCollectionIndexView) as I'm having the same need to implement one.